# :net contra Javascript

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

If do some client programmering, what factors should I take it into consideration if I gonnna use javascript/ECMAScript or .net in relation to retrieve some functionality from SharePoint and apply it to my client webpage?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difference between Client Object Model and Server Object Model in SharePoint 2010

Server Object Model:

1-SharePoint itself uses the server object model.You can also use this model on a sharepoint server bcz it has some dependencies satisfied by the sharepoint server.

2-Here you can use LINQ programming like LINQ to SharePoint.

3-different classes are there like SPFarm, SPServer, SPService, and SPWebApplication etc.

Client Object Model:

Client object model brings a major portion of that rich server-side functionality as a Client-side API, which can be used in a .NET client such as a WPF application, in a Silverlight application, or in a simple client such as ECMAScript. As Silverlight runs on the client rather than running server - side, the client Object Model (COM) makes it easier for developers to build rich Silverlight applications on SharePoint. The addition of Silverlight integration to SharePoint, a client object model is critical because it makes it easier for developers to write applications against a full object model, rather than trying to call web services from within their client applications.

.NET Client Object Model
To develop a .Net Managed application, reference two DLLs:

• Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll

• Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll

These files are usually installed into this directory:
%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\ISAPI

Silverlight Client Object Model
To develop a Silverlight application, use the following two assemblies:

• Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.dll

• Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.Runtime.dll

These files are usually installed into this directory:
%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ClientBin

ECMAScript Client Object Model
The JavaScript client object model consists of several JS files that are all installed into the LAYOUTS folder under the path %ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS:

•  SP.js/SP.debug.js
•  SP.Core.js/SP.Core.debug.js
•  SP.Runtime.js/SP.Runtime.debug.js
•  SP.Ribbon.js/SP.Ribbon.debug.js
•  JsGrid.js/JsGrid.debug.js
•  JSGrid.Gantt.js/JSGrid.Gantt.debug.js

Comment: Possible to use LINQ to SharePoint for a client?

Comment: Yes, refer to this site for implementation.
http://sumansharepoint.blogspot.in/2010/10/using-linq-in-client-object-model.html

Comment: If I create a ASP.net MVC page and what is the appropriate to use that is ECMA/JavaScript or .net client code?

Comment: Ideally speaking SP2010 object model doesn't support MVC framework. You should go for ECMA/Javascript.
Pls refer this link
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14986/integrating-asp-net-mvc-3-and-sharepoint

however you can go for SharePoint WebServices from your ASP.NET MVC app.

Comment: is it same for SharePoint 2013?

Comment: There is some change in 2013 mainly due to Apps introduction and Windows Azure integration with Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Pls have a look at this Question on this site regarding more about MVC.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70816/using-asp-net-mvc-with-sharepoint